# Proof of Kummer's Lemma in S. Langs 'Cyclotomic fields'

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I was going through the proof of Kummer's Lemma (stated below) as done in Serge Langs *Cyclotomic fields* on page 312.

Now the author states that by class field theory it suffices to show that $\mathbf{Q}(\xi_p, u^{1 / p})$ for a unit $u$ and a primitive $p$-th root of unity $\xi_p$ is unramified over $\mathbf{Q}(\xi_p)$. I do not see how this happens (or: this seems like magic to me) - could anyone explain this in a bit more detail?

Thanks for any help!

**Kummer's Lemma**: Let $p$ be a regular prime (i.e. an odd prime which does not divide the class number of the $p$-th cyclotomic field) and $\xi$ a primitive $p$-th root of unity; if a unit $u \in \mathbf{Q}(\xi)$ is congruent to an integer modulo $p$, then $u$ is a $p$-th power in $\mathbf{Q}(\xi)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$ contains the $p$th roots of unity, $K(u^{1/p})$ is the splitting field of $x^p - u \in K[x]$. But $x^p - u$ is either irreducible or splits into linear factors depending on whether $u^{1/p} \in K$, hence $K(u^{1/p})/K$ is Galois of degree dividing $p$. Thus the extension is necessarily abelian, so if it's unramified then it sits inside the Hilbert class field of $K$. But, by class field theory, the Hilbert class field of $K$ has degree over $K$ equal to $\# \mathrm{Cl}(K)$. So if $p$ doesn't divide $\# \mathrm{Cl}(K)$ then this would force $K(u^{1/p}) = K$.

Comment: Where does the hypothesis that u is congruent to an integer mod p intervene ?

Comment: Where does the hypothesis that u is congruent to an integer mod p intervene ? Note that thm.5.36 in Washington's "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields" is given a more detailed proof. Two proofs actually, one using class field theory, the other the p-adic regulator. Note also that Kummer's lemma is nowadays considered as an embryo of the celebrated Leopldt conjecture.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo The question asked why showing $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p, u^{1/p})/\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is unramified is enough. You need the condition that $u$ is congruent to an integer mod $p$ to actually show that it's unramified.

Comment: Actually, the condition that $u^{p-1}$ is congruent to 1 mod (p-1) is enough. See coroll. 2.3 in my paper  "Sur l'arithmétique des corps de nombres p-rationnels ", Sém. Théorie des Nombres, Paris 1987-88, pp. 155-200, in Progress in Math., vol.81, Birkhaäuser 1990, which also contains a vast generalization of Kummer's lemma .